# Call a function within a TypeScript Angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

For a while now, I've been following an Angular directive TypeScript pattern that I really like. I give the directive its own isolated `scope` by creating a new controller.

I've run into a situation where I need to call a function within my Angular directive from *outside* of the directive.

For example, I have a really simple function that opens a popup within my directive. The directive's controller has something like:

```
public openPopup() {
    this.uiClasses.popup = "open";
}
```

The corresponding view has a few notable elements like:

```
<div ng-click="vm.openPopup()">Open the pop up</div>
<div ng-class="vm.uiClasses.popup">the actual popup</div>
```

With some really basic CSS, this works like a charm. But, what if I have a controller that creates this directive, and wants to trigger the directive's `openPopup` function. I want to do something like this:

```
class PageController {
    private scope: any = null;
    static $inject = ["$scope"];

    constructor($scope: any) {
        $scope.vm = this;
    }

    public openTheDirectivePopup() {
        // from here, how can I call the openPopup on a specific directive?
    }
}
```

The corresponding view:

```
<div ng-click="vm.openTheDirectivePopup()">I can open the popup inside the custom directive</div>
<my-custom-directive></my-custom-directive>
```

I also want to be able to have multiple instances of these directives on the same page without conflict.

It seems like this should be do-able, but I can't quite wrap my head around it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do in that case is add a "isOpen" attribute to your directive, and toggle that value true / false from your `ng-click` call.

It would look like this in your HTML:

```
<div ng-click="vm.isOpen = true">I can open the popup inside the custom directive</div>
<my-custom-directive isOpen="vm.isOpen"></my-custom-directive>
```

Comment: That would certainly be a way to solve the actual problem I have - but, my question is actually about calling the function within the directive. Is this possible? Or would this approach be the only way to do something similar?

Comment: You would need a service to expose some of the logic to the outside. What I showed you is the most common way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: Awesome - that's exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks, @alcfeoh